# how to do regular expression replacer function in java?

Tags: java, python, regex

In python , I can use a replacer function in sub(), that is very powerful for some situation, like this:

```
def replacer(match):
    s = match.group(0)
    if s.startswith('/'):
        return ""
    else:
        return s
return re.sub(pattern, replacer, text)
```

how to do this in Java?

Comment: Write one yourself :-) Or, better yet, find a library that does this. It's about 10-15 lines of a helper function to walk through the match results and use substring to replace based on the results of invoking some interface with a String -> String (or whatnot) evaluator method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Java, there is an idiom:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(yourPattern);
Matcher matcher = patern.matcher(yourString);
while (matcher.find()) {
  String group = matcher.group(0);
  // do your if statement
}
```

One tip that's not readily apparent from the documentation - if yourString has special (reg exp) characters in it, it is important to use matcher.appendReplacement(stringBuffer) and matcher.appendTail(stringBuffer) to avoid errors.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do that in Java.

The replace* methods in the Matcher class take a String argument to specify the replacement.  What you are trying to do would require a replace method with a different signature.

You can't even hack a solution by creating a subclass of Matcher: it is a final class.

Comment: You can't do it in one line in Java.  (Of course you can't in Python either, hence defining a method.)  I don't see why using the matcher to loop wouldn't work though.

Comment: My point is that he can't do it the neat way he can in python; i.e. by plugging custom *behaviour* into the replacement process.  And I think that is what the question is *really* asking.